# Check if ipfs data exists

Tags: javascript, web3js, ipfs, ipfs-http-client

Using the [ipfs-http-client](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/tree/master/packages/ipfs-http-client) I can successfully add data using the below method. The `console.log(added)` returns an object with the `path`, `cid`, and `size` keys.

However, the `console.log(exists)` line returns `Object [AsyncGenerator] {}`.

I would like to be able to check if a data string exists. Is this possible?

```js
import { create as ipfsHttpClient } from 'ipfs-http-client'

const ipfsClient = ipfsHttpClient('https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0')

const handleData = async (data) => {
  const added = await ipfsClient.add(data)
  console.log(added)

  const exists = await ipfsClient.get(data)
  console.log(exists)
}

handleData('hello world')
```

Comment: Sorry, may be I'm blind, but I can't see `.get()` method in documentation

Comment: Not blind at all ... I thought that I found that somewhere ... but can't find it on the README

Comment: May this is reason? Or may be they removed this method? IDK :) But I will add point to your question to grow it up in list)

Comment: Most definitely appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The `get` method returns `AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>` object, which may be what you're printing out. To get each bytes, you will have to loop over it:

```
const cid = 'QmQ2r6iMNpky5f1m4cnm3Yqw8VSvjuKpTcK1X7dBR1LkJF'

for await (const buf of ipfs.get(cid)) {
  // do something with buf
  console.log(buf);
}
```

If all you care about is whether the data exists, you can just call `next()` method on the iterator and check for `null` or error.

```
const exists = (await ipfs.get(cid)).next() !== null
```